# Bot Framework v4 - Saving conversation references in Blob and reusing them after a new release

Tags: python, botframework, blob, microsoft-teams

I would like to save the conversation references to a blob file or SQL DB so that I can download this file and retrieve the conversation references and then send proactive messages to the users. I know that there is a sample that allows me to save the conversation references in a dictionary, but obviously this dictionary is deleted after a deployment of a new version of the bot and so I can't message the users anymore. So I thought to save this dictionary in a blob file in order to recover it and not to lose the conversation references. But this practice doesn't work.

I do the following to save the dictionary.

```
a = pickle.dumps(conversation_reference_dict)
blob_client.upload_blob(a, blob_type="BlockBlob", overwrite = True)
```

But I think this practice saves me a dictionary made like this : [id_client : address of the conversation_reference object] and this is clearly not what I want because after a future deployment this address will no longer mean anything.

Does anyone have any tips for doing this in python?
Thank you very much

UPDATE

After testing, the code is correctly saved in the dictionary. However, the problem arises when I try to execute the following code snippet after an update of the bot's source code.

```
# Send a message to all conversation members.
# This uses the shared Dictionary that the Bot adds conversation references to.
async def _send_proactive_message():
    for conversation_reference in CONVERSATION_REFERENCES_STORED.values():
        await ADAPTER.continue_conversation(
            conversation_reference,
            lambda turn_context: turn_context.send_activity("proactive hello"),
            APP_ID,
        )
```

The adapter method fails to continue the conversation with users, as if it no longer found them. Is there a way to update the conversation references that are saved in the blob so that after a release the bot can continue the pending conversations?

UPDATE II

I would like to work in this scenario:

- I have my bot quizzing users of a teams channel, the bot is released on azure and I can't go through the internal app section to teams due to lack of permissions.
- The bot works with proactive messages and saves the necessary conversation references to a file inside a blob.
- I want to introduce a new feature inside the bot so I perform a new release, I would like the bot to be able to continue proactively messaging users, since I save the conversation references to a file that is not touched by this release.

The last point doesn't happen, the proactive messages are no longer sent, is there any way I can continue to send these messages? I'm assuming that in the new bot release new id/url are created and these do not match the old id/url saved on the file and therefore calling the method of sending proactive messages via conversation reference will fail or otherwise not be executed. Does anyone know which fields do not match? Can I possibly send a message to the post-release bot and "modify" the entire dictionary on blob so that these urls/ids match?
I make an example of what i mean: i know that after a release the id1 is modified, so i after the release for example through the test section inside azure i contact the bot, this contact triggers a method that calls the file saved on azure it scrolls it all and replaces the old id1 with the new id1 so the sending of proactive messages can continue safely. is this a possible scenario? Can you help me?

UPDATE III

I seem to have solved my problem by adding this line of code:

```
AppCredentials.trust_service_url(conversation_reference.service_url)
```

before:

```
await ADAPTER.continue_conversation(
        conversation_reference,
        lambda turn_context: turn_context.send_activity("proactive hello"),
        APP_ID,
    )
```

resulting in this final code:

```
# Send a message to all conversation members.
# This uses the shared Dictionary that the Bot adds conversation references to.
async def _send_proactive_message():
    for conversation_reference in CONVERSATION_REFERENCES_STORED.values():
        AppCredentials.trust_service_url(conversation_reference.service_url)
        await ADAPTER.continue_conversation(
            conversation_reference,   
            lambda turn_context: turn_context.send_activity("proactive hello"),
            APP_ID,
        )
```

Comment: @VinothRajendran thank you for your interest, but it is useless to me :(

Comment: I'm pretty confused by this. When you say "address of the conversation_reference object" do you mean the local memory address? It's hard to imagine why blob storage would be saving things that way, since you can see that's useless. Can you provide an example of what your data looks like in the Python app and what the data looks like once it's in blob storage?

Comment: @KyleDelaney After careful study of the data, I noticed that the data is indeed stored well within the blob. However, the method that sends the proactive messages crashes and throws the "connection refused" exception because it is probably scrolling through all the conversation references and finds someone it cannot send a message to and blocks the whole process. Do you have any idea what property I need to look at to avoid this?The microsoft docs are not very clear. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botframework-schema/conversationreference?view=botbuilder-ts-latest

Comment: If you expect us to help you identify the problem with the way you're sending proactive messages then you'll need to show us how you're sending proactive messages

Comment: @KyleDelaney I send the proactive message as the famous sample available in the bot framework in various languages. The problem is that I have to add a check to the BotId or so it seems after the last experiments to send it only to the conversation references of the "live" bot are in the emulator.  Is there a simple way to retrieve this parameter?

Comment: I am asking you to edit code into your question. You cannot provide the needed information in comments. Please link to any samples you've been using as well.

Comment: I don't get notified when you make an edit, only when you comment. Also, you still haven't linked to the sample you're talking about

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney It seems to have solved my problem. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes, it is.

Comment: Why have you not accepted it?

Comment: what is the name of the package that has to be imported for AppCredentials

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal I have this string in my imports: `from botframework.connector.auth.app_credentials import AppCredentials`

Comment: @Scaramel after you make a update on bot and deploy, is the same still valid for you? Like whenever I make any update in the python code, I deploy it using zip deployment from az command line, but post that I am not able to send proactive messages, until I conversation is initiated by the user.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal Yes, it works. Do you save the dictionary containing the conversation_references somewhere outside the application (e.g. I save it in a blob by serialising it via the pickle library)? Because with each new deployment, this dictionary is instantiated again, which could be why you can't send the proactive messages. If  you can't find the conversation_references you can't find the user to write to anymore and so you need to have him present himself again.

Comment: @Scaramel can you please share the complete logic/flow for that

Comment: like how you convert the conversation reference to a file and vice-versa

Comment: okay, So I have been able to convert the Conversation_references to a dump at azure and read back from them, but the issue now is how do I update the CONVERSATION_REFERENCES variable, it is not getting updated. I assigned pickle.load(open("cr.p","rb")) to the variable, but it still stays blank

Comment: At last I finally found the solution for it, we have to use CONVERSATION_REFERENCES.update(c) instead of CONVERSATION_REFERENCES = c, this allowed it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this was removed from the docs, but you always need to trust the service URL in order to send proactive messages in Teams, as explained in this answer: [Proactive message not working in MS Teams after bot is restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63472410/proactive-message-not-working-in-ms-teams-after-bot-is-restarted/63472411#63472411)

EDIT: This is apparently no longer true for all languages, so you may not have to do it in Python for much longer